# Sorting iTunes Artist field

Tags: itunes, sorting

I'm trying to sort out my music and I have a couple of artists who have changed their name or have an album with solo tracks and some in a group.

Two examples are 'the game' and 'adam and the ants' (Yes I have eclectic taste)

There are two albums where the artist is 'game' but instead of having two entries in the artists on my ipod I'd like the 'game' tracks to appear under 'the game' but still have the artist displayed as 'game' if that makes sense.

With the other one there are some tracks by him solo and some with the ants so I have 'adam ant' and 'adam and the ants' but ideally I'd like the entire album to appear just under 'adam and the ants' so if I want to listen to the whole album I can from there (Yes I know I can find it from the albums menu)

Is this even possible? I've tried messing with the sort fields but I end up with several of each all containing the exact same albums and songs.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: (Per Comment) 
@Mike I'm sorry I misunderstood. Unfortunately, that is not currently a possible sorting option/ability within iTunes or on any iDevice. Your best option I believe would be to change the artist name

Comment: That's not quite it. I would like to keep the artists the same but have it treat it as if it is something else, in a similar way to how the 'sort artist' will let you choose where it appears in the list. Making 'the game' appear next to 'game' by changing 'the game' sort artist field to game.

Comment: @Mike I'm sorry I misunderstood. Unfortunately, that is not currently a possible sorting option/ability within iTunes or on any iDevice. Your best option I believe would be to change the artist name.

Comment: Ah no worries. no big deal . cheers

Comment: @Mike Alright I edited my answer to be the accurate answer to your problem. Have a good one :)